# Rails 3.2 not using bundled gems, Capistrano needs sudo gem install and rbenv not finding rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, rbenv

I have 2 Rails 3.2.11 apps running on an Ubuntu 12.04 server with Nginx, Unicorn and Postgresql. Deployment is by git and capistrano.

After I installed the second app I found that Capistrano would  fail during cap deploy because it "could not find a gem source" and I needed to install each missing gem using sudo. After this, cap deploy worked fine and so did the apps. Running bundle install from the current dir in either app reported using all the correct gems.

I am perplexed that Capistrano needs to find the gems before updating my app as my past experience (I think) was that I could run bundle install from the current dir to install any new or updated gems after cap deploy.

Today, I decided to update my Ruby version using rbenv on my dev laptop. I needed to run git pull from .rbenv/plugins/ruby-build and then rbenv rehash then I could install the new Ruby version. All good, ruby-v reports the new version 19.3-p374.

Now, when I run rails server (rails s) from my app dev dir I get rbenv: rails: command not found. The `rails' command exists in these Ruby versions: 1.9.3-p327. rbenv version reports
 1.9.3-p374. Rbenv which rails and bundle install both report "command not found: with rbenv error "The`rails' command exists in these Ruby versions: 1.9.3-p327".

So, two issues which I believe are related:-

1. How to make each app on my server independently run its own gems using bundle install? I don't want to freeze the gems and am quite happy to keep both apps up to date simultaneously. Should I just keep installing the required gems using sudo?
2. How to fix the rbenv issue of not finding rails in the new version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to reinstall all gems again. Gem install bundler and then bundle update from each application directory.